# FBSDKLog: WARNING: FBSDK secure network request failed.

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

...Please verify you have configured your app for Application Transport Security compatibility described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

We were getting App Transport Security errors in the simulator (Xcode 7 running on OSX 10.10.5). We implemented FB guidelines for iOS9.

FB graph api invoked was that based on SDK v.3.24.
The errors looked like those the Facebook documentation in lack of ATS info.plist configuration, i. e.:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```